# Solution of Laplace's equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $u(x,y)$ be a solution of Laplace equation on $x^{2}+y^{2}\leq1.$ If $$u(cos(\theta),sin(\theta))=\begin{cases} 
      sin\theta & 0\leq\theta\leq\pi \\
      0 & \pi\leq\theta\leq 2\pi  
   \end{cases}$$ 
Then $u(0,0)$ equals

$(a.)\frac{1}{\pi}$

$(b.)\frac{2}{\pi}$

$(c.)\frac{1}{2\pi}$

$(d.)\frac{\pi}{2}$

I don't know how to solve this problem. General solution of Laplace equation is very lengthy. I am trying to find the required value directly but $cos(\theta)$
 and $sin(\theta )$ are not simultaneously zero. How to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [mean value property of harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property), which simplifies for a function defined on the unit disk to the statement

$$u(0,0) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} u(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)\;d\theta.$$

Comment: ok sir thanks...i am reading first time this property...thanks a lot...